# python console to call function

Tags: python, console

I know this is an easy fix, but could someone tell me how to call a python file in the python Console who have this symbol: -.
Here is my mistake:

```
>>> import main #no error here
>>> import a1-devoir1
File "<input>", line 1
import a1-devoir1

Syntax Error: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `-` cannot appear in a module (or variable) name.

Comment: You might be able to hack something together with [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) but that would just cover the fact, that you used an invalid name. A module or package (or variable) can't contain a minus sign. Change the name of the file to `a1_devoir1`.

Answer (score 1):

You must name your files so that they only contains letters, underscores, or numbers (but not as the first character). All libraries and modules must follow this.

So rename your `.py` file to `a1_devoir` and then try `import a1_devoir`

Comment: we can call it if there is a '-'?

Comment: No `-` are allowed. Only underscores and characters.